# SQL Server : add data field from another table on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that shows duplicate rows in a table. Now I'm stuck on how to add data fields from another table into my query.

```
SELECT  
    T1.lname, T1.fname, T1.rtg_id
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         lname, fname, rtg_id
     FROM 
         cpmd b
     GROUP BY 
         lname, fname, rtg_id
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) >= 2) T1
JOIN 
    cpmd T2 ON T1.lname = T2.lname 
            AND T1.fname = T2.fname
            AND T1.rtg_id= T2.rtg_id
ORDER BY 
    lname, fname
```

This results in below result: (I removed the id in my actual query, just showed here for you)

```
md_id   lname   fname   rtg_id
------------------------------
9901    Smith   John    12300   
9902    Smith   John    12300   
9903    Lee     Bob     45600
9904    Lee     Bob     45600
```

I need to get the phone number and fax number of each person. Some records, although the same name, etc may have different phone and fax numbers. SO I need something like this:

```
md_id   lname   fname   rtg_id   Home            Fax
-------------------------------------------------------------
9901    Smith   John    12300   (654) 5894676   (231) 7684353
9902    Smith   John    12300   (546) 4576369    NULL   
9903    Lee     Bob     45600   (654) 9844576   (234) 2835657
9904    Lee     Bob     45600   (778) 6780853   NULL
```

These are the two tables that contain phone type and phone number.

`cpmd_phone` table:

```
md_id   phone_id    phone_type
------------------------------
9901    90          FAX 
9901    91          HOME
9902    92          FAX
9902    93          HOME
9903    94          FAX 
9903    95          HOME
9904    96          FAX
9904    97          HOME
```

`csphone` table

```
phone_id    area_code   phone_no
---------------------------------
90          231         7684353 
91          654         5894676
92          null        null    
93          546         4576369
94          234         2835657 
95          654         9844576
96          null        null
97          778         6780853
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work correctly. Sometimes it shows the 2 duplicates, sometimes it just show 1 record..

```
SELECT  
    T1.lname, T1.fname, T1.asmdid, T1.rtg_id, t1.Phone, T1.Fax   
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         lname, fname, rtg_id, 
         MIN(b.md_id) AS asmdid,
         MIN(CASE WHEN (d.phone_type_cn = 2) 
                     THEN '(' + e.area_code + ') ' + e.phone_no 
                     ELSE NULL 
             END) AS Phone,
         MIN(CASE WHEN (d.phone_type_cn = 4) 
                     THEN '(' + e.area_code + ') ' + e.phone_no 
                     ELSE NULL 
             END) AS Fax
     FROM 
         cpmd b
     JOIN 
         cpmd_phone d on b.md_id = d.md_id
     JOIN 
         csphone e ON d.phone_id = e.phone_id
     GROUP BY 
         lname, fname, rtg_id
    HAVING 
         COUNT(*) >= 2) T1
JOIN 
    cpmd T2 ON T1.lname = T2.lname 
            AND T1.fname = T2.fname
            AND T1.rtg_id = T2.rtg_id
            AND T1.asmdid <> T2.md_id
ORDER BY 
    lname, fname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case statement and a couple of joins...

```
SELECT  
    T1.lname, 
    T1.fname, 
    T1.rtg_id,
    Home = max(case when ph.phone_type = 'HOME' then '(' + cast(cs.area_code as char(3)) + ') ' + cast(cs.phone_no as char(7)) end),
    Fax = max(case when ph.phone_type = 'FAX' then '(' + cast(cs.area_code as char(3)) + ') ' + cast(cs.phone_no as char(7)) end)
FROM 
    (SELECT lname, fname, rtg_id
    FROM cpmd b
    GROUP BY lname, fname, rtg_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2) T1
JOIN cpmd T2 ON 
    T1.lname = T2.lname 
    AND T1.fname = T2.fname
    AND T1.rtg_id= T2.rtg_id
LEFT JOIN  cpmd_phone ph ON
    PH.md_id = t2.md_id
LEFT JOIN csphone cs ON
    cs.phone_id = ph.phone_id
GROUP BY
    T1.lname, 
    T1.fname, 
    T1.rtg_id,
ORDER BY lname, fname
```

Comment: this doesn't compile it says error on ph.phone_type and cs.phone_np 'Invalid column name'

Comment: I added an edit @shinratensei cs.phone_np was supposed to be cs.phone_no so a simple typeo.  There should be no error on ph.phone_type. What was the exact error?

Comment: well that's coming from the cpmd_phone table you have in your question... in that table you list phone_type. So is your sample data wrong?

Comment: It's compiling but it's not showing the home and fax number on the same line. md_id   lname   fname   rtg_id   Home            Fax
-------------------------------------------------------------
9901    Smith   John    12300   (654) 5894676   (231) 7684353
9902    Smith   John    12300   (546) 4576369    NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154564/discussion-between-shinra-tensei-and-scsimon).